AirflowException: Cannot execute spark-submit with Airflow - Error code 1
I'm trying to run a Spark job using Airflow, but I keep encountering an AirflowException. The task attempts to execute the following spark-submit command:
(tried with the path spark_jobs/sample.py also)
spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --name my_spark_job --deploy-mode client /opt/spark/spark_jobs/sample.py

However, the task fails with the following error:
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot execute: spark-submit --master spark://spark-master:7077 --name my_spark_job --deploy-mode client /opt/spark/spark_jobs/sample.py. Error code is: 1.

I've ensured that the Spark cluster is up and running, and the spark-submit command works when I execute it manually on the worker node.
Here are a few things I've checked so far:
The Spark master URL (spark://spark-master:7077) is correct.
The sample.py script is present at the specified path (/opt/spark/spark_jobs/sample.py).
The Airflow DAG is configured to run this task using the BashOperator.
What could be causing this issue? Are there any additional logs or configurations I should check? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
